# Read/Write parquet file with golang

Tags: go

Recently I want to write and read(mostly write) parquet file with golang. Is there any good tools and library? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This project is used for reading/writing parquet file:

https://github.com/xitongsys/parquet-go

Answer (score 0):

There's also https://github.com/xitongsys/parquet-go which to me seems to have a little bit simpler API